# Problema al referenciar servicio web WCF desde app MVC

Tags: wcf

Tengo un servicio web alojado en un proyecto creado con WFC. El servicio se publica correctamente en el cliente de prueba de WFC, desde donde lo puedo invocar y me entrega datos de manera normal. Cabe señalar que el tipo de datos devuelto por el servicio es una lista de enteros

En otra solución, tengo otro proyecto que consume este servicio web, para lo cual he realizado las siguientes pruebas, y todas me dan el mismo resultado.

1.- Refereneciar el servicio a través de una *Service Reference*, tras lo cual al instanciarlo me entrega el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Message   "No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace referencia al contrato 'ICarroService' en la sección de configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no se encontró ningún elemento de extremo correspondiente a este contrato en el elemento de cliente."   string

2.- Luego de que eso no funcionara, en algún foro por ahí, vi que había que copiar desde el *app.config* la sección `<system.serviceModel>`, la cual describe claramente el *EndPoint*, y la copié en el *web.config* de mi aplicación MVC que es la que está consumiendo el servicio, y aun así no funciona, y me entrega el mismo mensaje de error.

3.- Opté entonces por generar el proxy a través de la ejecución del comando `svcutil`, lo cual me generó el proxy y un archivo de configuración, los cuales copié en el proyecto que consume el *web service*, e instancié la clase directamente en el proyecto, pero aun así no funciona y entrga el mismo error.

¿Alguna idea que me puedan sugerir para poder revisar?

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro.CarroService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro.ICarroService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro/CarroService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: El escenario que planteas como tal, deja lugar a muchas dudas, por ejemplo, ¿el WCF lo tienes publicado en algún IIS? ¿Cuál es la definición que te pone en el `<system.ServiceModel>`? ¿Cuál es la definición del *endpoint*? ¿Tienes publicado el servicio en alguna ruta donde lo podamos ver para intentar replicar el escenario?

Comment: Hla, mira, el servicio esta publicado en forma virtual a traves del cliente de pruebas de visual studio., no lo he publicado en el IIS, porque no tengo acceso a manipular el IIS (temas de seguridad). ahora, el problema, segun creo, se da al parecer porque la aplicacion cliente que consume el servicio, no encuentra la definicion del endpoint a pesar que la inclui en el web.config. Aca dejo la definicion del <system.serviceModel> para que la puedan ver, anque creo que ese no es el problema, porque como te comentaba desde el cliente de pruebas si puedo usar el servicio (invocarlo).

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro.CarroService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro.ICarroService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>

Comment: <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.SVC.Carro/CarroService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: recuerda que la información va en la pregunta, lo mejor sería editar la pregunta con esta información para que esté más completa y tenga mayor atención para otros usuarios.

Comment: ah si, disculpa, pense que aca tb se veria bien

Comment: ¿Al tener la dirección `http://localhost:8733/....` te estás refiriendo a que lo tienes publicado en tu IIS local o es la dirección que genera cuando corres tu proyecto WCF en modo `debug`? Si es la segunda opción me temo que a eso se debe el error, lo ideal es que publiques tu proyecto como mínimo en tu IIS local para que puedas consumirlo incluso desde otros proyectos.

Comment: Hola, mira.. el tema estaba un poco raro... resulta que por ejemplo, si echaba a correr el WS como lo estaba haciendo (modi debug) en el cliente de WS que trae VS, y por otro lado consumia el servicio con una aplicacion de consola por ejemplo, en donde referenciaba al servicio (que si lo hace siempre) funcionaba bien. desde donde no funcionaba, era desde mi actual aplicacion MVC, que es desde donde necesitaba el dato.

Comment: Asi que me di la tediosa tarea de partir con un proyecto MVC nuevo, donde volvi a copiar todas las bibliotecas que estan en el proyecto.. y .. adicionalmente le agregre un proyecto classlibrary, desde donde referencie nuebvamente el servioc, y funciono sin problemas.. creo que en alguna parte, eche a perder la solucion, o habia algo por ahi que no me funcionaba en el congig..  bueno, de tofdas formas muchas gracias por tu ayuda. saludos